# How to check if a pointer to a char array points at a digit character?

Tags: c, char, arrays

I have a pointer to a char array. I want to increase it until it will not point at a digit / number (represented as a char in the char array).

For example, if `pointer` points to `'2'` in this char array:

```
['1'][' ']['2']['3']['4'][' '][' '][' ']['5']['6']['7']
            ^
         *pointer
```

I want to increase it until it will point at the first non-digit character - `' '`:

```
['1'][' ']['2']['3']['4'][' '][' '][' ']['5']['6']['7']
                           ^
                        *pointer
```

I know I can do something like this:

```
while (*pointer == '0' || *pointer == '1' || *pointer == '2' || ...)
    pointer++;

return pointer;
```

but it's pretty long and not elegant at all.

I thought I could use `atoi()`, which returns `0` when the pointer doesn't point at a number:

```
while (atoi(pointer) != 0 || *pointer == '0') //while it still points at a number
    pointer++; //increase the pointer until it will not point at a number

return pointer;
```

But it doesn't seem to work. Maybe it's okay and I have a mistake somewhere else, but anyway I wanted to know:

Are there are any other (better) ways to check whether a pointer to a char array points at a digit / number and increase it until it will point at a non-digit character, in C?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should probably use `isdigit` from `ctype.h` instead. Something like:

```
while (*pointer && isdigit(*pointer))
    pointer++;
```

Comment: Doesn't `isdigit()` return false if its argument is the 0 terminator?

Comment: @H2CO3 Don't know so not risking it.

Comment: I guess `isdigit` does what AshRj proposed in his answer?

Comment: @tempy Not necessarily. In practice it can be implemented with an array masked with a constant. See Plauger, chapter 2.

Comment: `isdigit` is defined to return true if and only if the argument is a decimal-digit character, which is defined to be one of the decimal digits 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, or 9. Therefore, the `*pointer &&` portion is not needed. Some of the other ctype functions might not be safe because they depend on locale, and perhaps an evil user might define a locale in which null is a printing character or a letter, et cetera. (I do not know much about locales. Perhaps that is prevented in some way?)

Comment: Quick question: if I want to send a `const char *p` pointer as an argument to a function and make it change in the `main` as the functions changes it - what should I do? Can I do it without a return?

Comment: @EricPostpischil You're probably right. I wish the standard mentioned ctypes.h **must** work with 0 though.

Comment: @tempy Not sure I understand. If it's const the function can't change its contents.

Comment: @cnicutar What I mean is that when a function increases the pointer - `p++`, it will be increased in the `main` as well, so it will point at the next cell of the array in the `main` as well as inside the scope of the function.

Comment: @tempy Ah. Then you probably want to pass a double pointer. As a matter of style however, I would have the function return either a pointer or an offset.

Comment: I know this is a pretty old question, but its worth noting for others that see this that the OP stated use of a char array with ASCII data, NOT a string, i.e. the array may not be NULL terminated. If using this code, the while loop should be altered to check the pointer remains within array limits to ensure safety.

Answer (score 2):

```
while (*pointer >= '0' && *pointer <= '9')
    pointer++;

return pointer;
```

Comment: I thought about it but it didn't seem safe. Is it?

Comment: @H2CO3 why it's not safe? Could you clarify please.

Comment: It is safe in at least C 1999 and later. The character digits are specified to be consecutive in the source and the execution character sets. It would not be safe with letters, as testing for `*pointer >= 'a' && *pointer <= 'z'`.

Answer (score 1):

As the digits have consecutive values in ASCII and UTF-16, you can subtract the value of '0' from the value of the character to get the single digit decimal equivalent *(if it is a single digit decimal)*, and then test the value.

```
while(*pointer-'0'>=0 && *pointer-'0'<=9) pointer++;
```

Or simply do this :

```
while(*pointer>='0' && *pointer<='9') pointer++;
```

Comment: Why the downvote ? Atleast comment/correct me if you know this is incorrect

Comment: I did not down vote, but this is wasteful; there is no reason to perform subtraction. You can simply compare directly to `'0'` and `'9'`, as shown in other answers, or use `isdigit`. Generally, when a library routine does precisely what is desired, it is preferable to use it, since one may expect that it has been optimized for the purpose.

Comment: Technically, this could cause undefined behavior. The `char` type could be signed, and `*pointer-'0'` could be outside the range of an `int`. (Per other discussion on StackOverflow, a perverse C implementation may have the same width for `char` and `int`.) Then you would have overflow in a signed integer type, which is undefined. This is generally only of educational value; practical C implementations do not do this.

Comment: This method is easier to understand than a simple character comparison (or atleast i found this more logical and useful than a direct comparison when i was starting out), and the OP seems to be starting out

Comment: **educational value** -> Exactly why i posted this

Comment: +1 @EricPostpischil I did not think of that. Yes, then this would not work.

Comment: @EricPostpischil IS it alright if i added that to the answer ? That is something that many would not think of ..

Comment: Sure. The possibility of undefined behavior is quite esoteric in this code, however; it really is not a problem in normal C implementations.